# How to integrate KCFinder inside zend application as standalone

Tags: php, zend-framework, integration

I want to integrate KCFinder inside Zend framework, i want this

**http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/demo/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files&dir=files/public**

page to be included inside my template without using any iframe, i had tried many things by calling browser.php file inside my view but i am facing issues with file loading and their dependencies, even resolving php file dependency by using autoloader js files are not loading properly

Please help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

I had collaborated  with project like CKfinder called [Elrte.org](http://elrte.org/) 
and i did make a custom ZF form element for it

a sample example on my github account :

https://github.com/tawfekov/Elrte-Element-for-Zend-Framework

the demo has ability to show the rich text editor + file manager

feel free to extend it or to get an example of it